# Subsonic 3 Hierarchic Collection Creation?

Tags: collections, subsonic, subsonic3, hierarchical-data

I have a single table with a hierarchy inside. I am using ActiveRecord. How can I convert this into a hierarchic collection that I can then bind to a WinForms or WPF treeview?

Thanks.

```
ID  Name    ParentID
1   ALL 1
2   ARGENTINA   1
15  AUSTRALIA   1
16  NW  15
17  BLACKTOWN   16
18  CORLETTE    16
19  PRIMBEE 16
20  TWEED HEADS 16
21  QL  15
22  ASHMORE 21
23  ROBERTSON   21
24  TOOWOOMBA   21
25  TRINITY BEACH   21
26  UNITED STATES   1
27  AK  26
28  CA  26
29  NJ  26
30  NIKISKI 27
31  AMADOR CITY 28
32  MOSS BEACH  28
33  Essex   29
34  Newark  33
35  Ampere  33
36  Avondale    33
37  Beaufort    33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a partial class and add the property Children (or whatever makes sense).

```
public IList<MyClass> Children.
```

Then, in a method somewhere (in your repo, BLL, whatever), loop and load:

```
var items=MyClass.All().ToList();

items.ForEach(x=>x.Children=items.Where(y=>y.ParentID==x.ID).ToList());
```